# PagedList in MVC3 showing Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, pagedlist

**This is My View**

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("CrmBlogGroupType","knowledge",FormMethod.Get)){
       @Html.TextBox("search") 
         @Html.Hidden("type", (string)ViewBag.type)
           @Html.DropDownList("PageSize",
        new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
             new SelectListItem ()
        {
        Text="--Select Page Size--" ,Value="10",Selected=true
        },
        new SelectListItem ()
        {
        Text="View 20 records" ,Value="20"
        },
        new SelectListItem ()
        {
        Text="View 50 records" ,Value="50"
        },
          new SelectListItem ()
        {
        Text="View 100 records" ,Value="100"
        },
        })
           <input type="submit" value="search" id="Searchbtn" />
         <br />
           @Html.CheckBox("Name")<text>Author Name</text>
           @Html.CheckBox("AuthorTitle")<text>Title</text>
           @Html.CheckBox("Description")<text>Description</text>
       }
```

**Here is the PagedList Code**

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("CrmBlogGroupType", 
new     {page,Name=Request.QueryString["Name"].ToLower().Contains("true"),
AuthorTitle=Request.QueryString["AuthorTitle"].ToLower().Contains("true"),
Description=Request.QueryString["Description"].ToLower().Contains("true"),      search=Request.QueryString["search"],PageSize=Request.QueryString["PageSize"],type=Request.QueryStrin g["type"]}),new PagedListRenderOptions() 
{ 
   DisplayLinkToFirstPage=true,DisplayLinkToLastPage=true,DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation=true,Displa      yItemSliceAndTotal=true
    ,DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers=true,MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay=10
})
```

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult CrmBlogGroupType(int? page, bool? Name, bool? AuthorTitle, bool?Description, string search, int? PageSize, string type)
    {

        if (type==null)
        {
            //setting the Value in the initial call 
            //If the SP has changed then make the type parameter as the INT
            type = "A";
        }

        IEnumerable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> _objBlogSet = _dataLayer.GetBlogSet(type).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, PageSize ?? 10);
        return View(_objBlogSet);
        }
```

**Getting an ERROR :**

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Line 202:    @if (ViewBag.Search!=null && ViewBag.Search!=string.Empty)            
Line 203:{
Line 204:@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("CrmBlogGroupType", new { page,
Line        205:Name=Request.QueryString["Name"].ToLower().Contains("true"),AuthorTitle=Request.QueryString["Auth    orTitle"].ToLower().Contains("true"),
Line 206:Description=Request.QueryString["Description"].ToLower().Contains("true"),
```

I've gone through some links by which i could make up the code like this, at last got stuck here
Any help on this is highly appreciated..

Comment: `Request.QueryString["Something"]` can always be `null` if it doesn't exist in the request url, and it will cause the exception when you are trying to do `ToLower()` to `null`, you have to do null check on them, or figure out a way to avoid the view getting rendered in controller when something you need is null.

Comment: every time I have seen that error it was from using a list that wasn't instantiated.  Make sure you have done that for all of your lists.

Comment: Use the ViewBag for passing the various parameters to the `PagedListPager`. Calculate the values in the controller and don't have complex logic in a view. Pulling parameters from querystring, *when the controller has strongly typed values for those*, is a waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ViewBag` for passing the various parameters to the `PagedListPager`. Calculate the values in the controller and don't have complex logic in a view. Pulling parameters from `querystring`, *when the controller has strongly typed values for those*, is an unnecessary duplication of effort.

```
public ActionResult CrmBlogGroupType(int? page, bool? Name, bool? AuthorTitle, bool?Description, string search, int? PageSize, string type)
{
    // Get the current values (or defaults == false) for the sorting
    ViewBag.Name = Name.GetValueOrDefault();
    ViewBag.AuthorTitle = AuthorTitle.GetValueOrDefault();
    ViewBag.Description= Description.GetValueOrDefault();
```

and use them in the view like this:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("CrmBlogGroupType", 
    new {page, Name=ViewBag.Name, AuthorTitle=ViewBag.AuthorTitle, Description=ViewBag.Description
```

etc

**Update: 10,000 records is currently slow**

From the comments below the current paging is slow. That is because the `ToList()` in the following line causes all records to be returned *before any paging is applied to the LINQ query*.

```
IEnumerable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> _objBlogSet = 
        _dataLayer.GetBlogSet(type)
        .ToList()             // <<<< THIS IS THE CULPRIT
        .ToPagedList(page ?? 1, PageSize ?? 10);
```

`ToPagedList` is designed to work an an `IQueryable` so that when it adds `Skip(n)` and `Take(n)` to the query it will efficiently return just the page worth of records. Simply remove the `ToList()`:

```
IEnumerable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> _objBlogSet = 
        _dataLayer.GetBlogSet(type)
        .ToPagedList(page ?? 1, PageSize ?? 10);
```

Comment: TrueBlueAussie and @tweray You're right about it.. Storing the Values in the ViewBag did the trick.. Thank you so much for all your help..

Comment: @user3759894: PagedList is very useful, but you need a good example to follow for the implementation pattern. I started mine with the basic pattern shown on the GitHub source (https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) and kept extending that.

Comment: Thank you @TrueBlueAussie... Currently there are around 10 thousand records on which i'm performing search is there any way I could make it much faster with the pagedList .. Recently I've worked with the webgrid which is little faster when compared with the paged list... However I would like to use stick with the paged list with improved speed... Is there any way ?

Comment: You need to get rid of the `ToList()` as you are querying all 10,000 records then creating the paged list. The ToPagedList will add `skip(n)` and `take(n)` so it needs to be an IQueryable (not a list).

Comment: Sorry @TrueBlueAussie i'm New to mvc , this is what i'm doing in the datalayer, This method retrieves the 10,000 records and i'm performing the search on the returned records. How do you want me to proceed with it..? Below is the code

 public List<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> GetBlogSet(string type)
        {
             List<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> Obj= _dbContext.Usp_getBlogSetPosts(type.ToString()).ToList();
             return Obj;
        }

Comment: This is how I'm doing the search in the controller :

IEnumerable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> _objBlogSet = _dataLayer.GetBlogSet(type);
            if (Name == true && AuthorTitle == false && Description == false)
            {
                _objBlogSet = _objBlogSet.Where(p => p.author_name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, PageSize ?? 10);
            }

Comment: @Dathatreya: Answer updated to cover this issue. Hope it helps :)